# The probability of an observation belonging to one or other sample

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, inference, contingency-tables

Assume I asked 10 children and 10 adults whether they like my cake. 9 kids did and 1 didn't, while for the adults it was the reverse. Using these data, can I say that any random person who likes my cake is more likely to be a child than an adult? Is it possible to put an exact probability on this guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ denote being a child and $C'=A$ being an adult. Similarly, let $L$ denote liking the cake. Then, based on the data, we can *estimate* the following probabilities for the population:
$$P(L|C)=0.9, \ \ P(L|C')=0.1$$
On your sample we have $P(C)=P(C')=0.5$ since number of adults and children are the same. But, you can also assign prior probabilities to these groups, e.g. probability of a randomly chosen person being a child is $0.3$ for example. But, this is not inferred from the data.

What we're interested in is $P(C|L)$, which can be expanded via Bayes Rule:

$$P(C|L)=\frac{P(L|C)P(C)}{P(L)}=\frac{P(L|C)P(C)}{P(L|C)P(C)+P(L|C')P(C')}$$

Once agreed on priors, the rest is substitution.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much!